# Unable to feed array with az output

Tags: bash, azure

I query the list of all the resource group names in my Azure subscription. This is OK:

`az group list --subscription "${subscription}" --output table | awk '{print $1}'`

Then I need to have this list in an array in bash, but I keep getting syntax error:

This one lists them, but the array length is 0:

```
#!/bin/bash
subscription="$*"
#Get the Resource Groups names
rg_array= az group list --subscription "${subscription}" --output table | awk '{print $1}'
echo "${#rg_array[@]}"
```

If I use bracketts, I get syntax error:

```
#!/bin/bash
subscription="$*"
#Get the Resource Groups names
rg_array= (az group list --subscription "${subscription}" --output table | awk '{print $1}')
echo "${#rg_array[@]}"
```

...

```
test.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
test.sh: line 8: 'rg_array= (az group list --subscription "${subscription}" --output table | awk '{print $1}')'
```

Comment: In bash you cannot have spaces around `=`. Use `rg_array=...` instead. Do `rg_array=$(stuff)`

Comment: You have a space after `rg_array`. Also, you want to catch the stdout of `az`. Hence you need `( $(az ....) )`.

Comment: @user1934428 so, it should look like this? `rg_array=( $(az group list --subscription "${subscription}" --output table) ) | awk '{print $1}'`

Comment: This would assign the output of the az command to `rg_array`, but you would not pipe anything to `awk`, so the `awk` command does not make much sense. Note that the command inside `$( ... )` needs to produce whatever you want to catch. If you want to catch the output of the `awk` command (not the `az` command), that one has to be inside the parenthesis of course too. But I don't know exactly, what you want to capture.

Comment: @fishmong3r Try: `rg_array=( $(az group list --subscription "${subscription}" --output table | awk '{print $1}' ) )`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
foo=$((az group list --subscription "Your Subscription" --output table | awk '{print $1}' | awk '{if(NR>2)print}' ) | tr '\r\n' ' ')

IFS=' ' read -r -a bar <<< $foo

# Access individual elements
echo "${bar[0]}"
```

Then you can iterate over the array to access invidual elements.